# Does all adamantine gear deteriorate in sunlight?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, special-materials

Adamantine armour/weapons made by the drow are said to degrade if exposed to sunlight, but does this apply to gear crafted from adamantine by other races as well?

Comment: Can you include a reference to a source that says that drow-made adamantine weapons degrade if exposed to sunlight? As it stands, I suspect this question is based on a faulty premise.

Comment: @Miniman Drow-made magic items and adamantine gear degrading in sunlight is a thing from earlier editions' versions of the Forgotten Realms, I believe. I don't know if it's been carried forward into 5e.

Comment: @GMJoe Oh, I know it features heavily in FR books, but I get the impression the question is meant to be about D&D 5e, hence why I was wondering about the OP's source.

Comment: @Miniman It predates FR.  That detail comes from EGG's original module.  [See the deleted answer for details](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/60383/22566).

Answer (score 34):

## No, sunlight-sensitive gear is a Drow-specific thing, not a general property of adamantine

(OOC -- what do Drow make their gear from? PVC with no UV-resistance modifiers? :P)

The applicable entries are p. 142 of the DMG for Drow-made gear:

> **Drow.** The item is half the normal weight.  It is black and inscribed with spiders and webs in honor of Lolth.  It might function poorly, or disintegrate, if exposed to sunlight for 1 minute or more.

and p. 150 for Adamantine Armor:

> #### Adamantine Armor
>
> *Armor (medium or heavy, but not hide), uncommon*
>
> This suit of armor is reinforced with adamantine, one of the hardest substances in existence.  While you're wearing it, any critical hit against you becomes a normal hit.

Note that the description of the latter says *nothing* about who made it, or whether it's sunlight-sensitive or not, so it's rather safe to assume it's not sunlight sensitive by default.  Double-check with your DM, of course, though!

Comment: "what do Drow make their gear from? PVC with no UV-resistance modifiers?" - it's likely that all adamantine has magic woven into it, and the magic used by them depends on the darkness and is harmed by sunlight.

Comment: Whatever the drown make their gear from - something happens to make it half normal weight.  I suspect that's what would cause Drow Adamantine to turn to tissue paper.

Comment: @Shalvenay Random832 is pretty close to the cannon explanation. In older editions' versions of the Forgotten Realms setting, almost all Drow-made magic was dependant on a kind of magical ambient radiation common in the underdark but not found on the surface, and which was gradually degraded by direct exposure to sunlight.

Comment: @GMJoe -- understood re: FR canon on UD magic -- the line about PVC with no UV-resistance modifiers was a joke about material properties ;)

Comment: @Shalvenay Heh, I thought that might be the case.  I figured the FR explanation might be useful information for readers looking for an in-setting justification for this rule, though.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally go with the "specific beats general". The description for Drow made gear lists, on page 142 (DMG) in the table *Who created it or was intended to use it?*, as:

> **Drow**. The item is half the normal weight. It is black and inscribed with spiders and webs in honor of Lolth. It might function poorly, or disintegrate, if exposed to sunlight for 1 minute or more. [sic]

This quality likely holds true for most general Drow made gear. Note the reference to "might" in the description which gives your DM a lot of leeway to interpret the rule and might allow gear that is not harmed by sunlight. For example, why would clay pots start disintegrating if they were made by Drow instead of Dwarves? Moreover, this table should be used for RP flair in my opinion and less to actually determine physical qualities of an item that you acquire. But that is up to the DM.

On the other hand, Adamantine Armour is a very specific item with very specific qualities that are listed on page 150 of the DMG as:

> **Adamantine Armor**
>
> *Armor (medium or heavy, but not hide), uncommon*
>
> This suit of armor is reinforced with adamantine, one of the hardest substances in
> existence. While you're wearing it, any critical hit against you
> becomes a normal hit. [sic]

While nothing would contradict, at least not in the RAW an Adamantine Armour made by Drows that disintegrates in sunlight, I'd be cautious with having these magic items be of the same rarity. After all they may have a drawback (if it is Drow made) or an advantage if made by another race.

Finally I'd like to offer food for thought; no other description that I skimmed through on the table I mentioned above contains any concrete rules and most contain only flavour text. If introducing disadvantages, be sure to balance RP and combat function of said items.

Comment: The reason why drow gear disintegrated was almost certainly to deny players treasure, while giving drow NPCs-built-like-PCs magic toys to use.  They have +4 swords, +3 armor, wands of badassery -- but the gear melted away when the players took it back to down as loot.

Comment: As I said, it can be. But one needs to be careful when to apply it and to what items. I am not saying it is not possible or that this isn't how it used to be. But in 5e magic items are designed to be quite rare if following the RAW. Hence, GMs need to be aware of how to apply the Drow trait consistently with the game's design in mind. That being said, the question was simply on the traits of race-specific gear

Comment: @Yakk There was nothing "almost" about that. Gygax' early modules had quite a bit of "DM versus Player" tone to them.

Answer (score 0):

The drow themselves do not create adamantine weapons. They only buy it from the duergars and enchant it. So the enchantment would be destroyed by sunlight, but the weapon itself wouldn't.

Comment: That seems like an interesting point, but can you support your answer somehow? If you can find sources to back up your statements, this answer would be improved a lot.

Comment: I'd love to see the lore/source on that, even if it is from an earlier edition or a Dragon Mag article.  Got a source? (You have stirred a vague/long ago memory with that ... )  Sounds like something from 2e AD&D ... sorry memory is very foggy on that.  The original 1e module had the items themselves rotting and falling apart.